# Django: getting objects with ids from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have these models (names are changed):

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    created_dtm = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_dtm = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Authors, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class BlogAuthor(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('blog', 'author')
```

and I need to get all Blogs(and its details) in which author is involved.
The problem is that each Blog can have more than one author.

Now I can get query set of Blog's ids using this:

```
BlogAuthor.objects.filter(author=request.user).values_list('blog_id', flat=True)
```

and then try getting every single Blog one by one using cycle `for`, but is it possible to get list of Blogs with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
Blog.objects.filter(blogauthor__author=request.user)
```